# Why does $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\lfloor{x^2}\rfloor}{x^2}$ not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\lfloor{x^2}\rfloor}{x^2}$$

$\lfloor x^2 \rfloor = 0 \space \forall x \in (-1,1)$ and $x^2 > 0 \space \forall \space x$ in the vicinity of $0$ but not at $0$. Hence this limit should be $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{x^2} = 0$.

The answer key in my textbook and GeoGebra, however, seem to disagree with this. Both claim that the limit is undefined. Why is this so?

Comment: This limit is most definitely $0$. I don't know why GeoGebra seems to disagree but your textbook is likely incorrect.

Comment: The limit is $0$. See also https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+-%3E+0+%28floor+%28x%5E2%29%29+%2F+x%5E2

Comment: Geogebra only does a numerical approximation so dont trust it for exact answers

Comment: You're correct. As you said, the function is identically $0$ on a (deleted) neighborhood of $0$, so its limit at $0$ is also $0$.

Comment: I would say that $\lim_{x\to 0, \,x \neq 0}\frac{\lfloor x^2\rfloor}{x^2} =0$. However, the problem with writing $\lim_{x\to 0}$ is that one way to approach zero is to take $x = 0$ for which the ratio is undefined. In that sense, I tend to agree with your textbook.

Comment: @Michh By that argument, the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x$ does not exist. Actually, no derivative whatsoever exists.

Comment: I may be wrong as your argument is compelling, but I think in the case of derivatives it is implicitly meant that $h \to 0$ and $h \neq 0$. Otherwise, one would get: for every $\epsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ such that $$|h|< \delta \implies \left| \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}- f'(x)\right| <\epsilon$$ which makes no sense for $h = 0$ (which is not excluded). @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limit exists and is equal to zero. Consider any sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converging to zero, none of whose terms is zero. Then,
$$f(x_n)=\dfrac{\lfloor x_n^2\rfloor}{x_n^2}=0\,\forall n>N$$
where $N$ is a number such that $|x_n|<1\forall n>N$. Therefore, given limit is zero by sequential criteria.

Comment: Or as the OP noted using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition we can always choose $\delta=1$ for any $\epsilon\gt0$.

Comment: Why do you provide a proof which is longer than the one provided by the OP?

Comment: @PeterForeman, yes, that is equivalent to that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, this is equivalent to the one provided by the OP, just another way to view that.